# Compression of a file in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need to compress a file into gunzip and it is done by below command

@echo off
gzip -c C:\temp1\xx.out > C:\temp2\x2.out.gz

But my req is to check all files in a directory which has extension .out and compress each file into gunzip file and remove the same file after compression is done .Please let me know how it can be done in batch script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   rem Pick up each file in C:\Temp1\ with .out extension.
   for %%a in ("C:\temp1\*.out") do (

        rem Compress the file to a file with the same name but .gz extension is added.
        gzip -c %%a > %%a.gz

        rem Delete the .out file which has been already compressed.
        del /F /Q %%a
    )
```

Comment: It is best practice to explain your answer a bit.  Working mysteries are still mysteries